# Having Troubles Upgrading Artifactory 3.5.3-0 to 4.4

Tags: tomcat, migration, upgrade, derby, artifactory

I have Artifactory 3.5.3-0 installed on a Windows Server and it is using the Derby internal DB.
I am trying to upgrade to 5.6 PRO.
It looks like jFrog recommends upgrading to 3.9, then 4.x, then to 5.x.
It seems like my directory structure is different than normal installs.  I see a lot of Artifactory pages that mention the tomcat folder in the Artifactory_Home Directory.  I don't have a tomcat folder, I have an apache-tomcat directory.  I have tried different upgrade attempts and continuously fail.

My current Directory structure is:
D:\artifactory\artifactory-3.5.3-0\apache-tomcat
Inside this apache-tomcat folder is:
bin
conf
lib
logs
scripts
temp
webapps
work
bnconfig.exe
LICENSE
NOTICE
RELEASE-NOTES
RUNNING.txt
I also have a directory such as:
D:\artifactory\artifactory-3.5.3-0\apps\artifactory_home\
and other directories.

My two Windows Services are:
artifactoryApache (which runs "D:\ARTIFA~1\ARTIFA~1.3-0\apache2\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice)
artifactoryTomcat (which runs "D:\ARTIFA~1\ARTIFA~1.3-0\apache2\bin\tomcat7.exe //RS//artifactory Tomcat)

I have tried this and got it to upgrade to 3.9 but I can't get beyond 3.9:
Stop Artifactory Services
Download zip folder artifactory-3.9.0.zip (Currently in Brian's

Downloads folder on his workstation)
Extract zip folder.
Delete atifactory folder in:
D:\artifactory\artifactory-3.5.3-0\apache-tomcat\webapps
Replace artifactory.war file in:
D:\artifactory\artifactory-3.5.3-0\apache-tomcat\webapps
Restart Artifactory Services.

Can anyone shed any light on why my install structure is laid out differently than what jFrog shows for their documentation?  I installed artifactory a few years back but I recall using all the defauls the exe walked me through.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the installed JDK version -

From version 4.0, Artifactory requires JDK 8. If your current version is v3.x, before you upgrade to Artifactory 5.x, please make sure you install JDK 8 and update your JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to your JDK 8 installation.